# Obtaining #NUM when using LARGE with dates array

Tags: excel

I'm getting a #num error to a previously working formula.

Formula:

```
=LARGE(A19:A20,1)



FORMULA OUTPUT: #NUM!

A19:    3/20/2018
A20:    5/1/2018
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working anymore.

Regards,

Comment: Make sure your dates are actual dates and not text that look like dates.

Comment: They are custom field "MM/DD/YYYY"

Comment: try changing the format of the cells and see if it changes, if it does not change then it is text.

Comment: It doesn't change automatically. But it never seems to change? How can I make sure I set it properly?

Comment: If it does not change it is text and not a true date.  You can use the formula as described in the answer below.  As to changing it in place it depends on how the values are being placed in the cells.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is Text and not true dates, use this array formula:

```
=LARGE(--(A19:A20),1)
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

NOTE:

This formula will work for both real dates and text that resemble dates.  It is easy to see if the dates are real or not; just toggle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>.  Real dates will display their underlying numeric value, text date will remain unchanged.

Comment: In doing that, I now get a #value error. I did both with the crl + shift + enter and did you --(array) formula.

Comment: @JPFoster  You will get that error if there are any **spaces** in the data cells, also make sure your **Regional** date formats match the formats of the data.

Comment: I'm using custom fields as MM/DD/YYYY for all the fields